# Export cassandra query result to a csv file

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I'm new in cassandra, and I have to export the result of a specific query to a csv file.

I found the `COPY` command, but (from what I understand) it allows you only to copy an already existing table to a csv file, and what I want is to copy directly the stdout of my query to the csv file. is there any way to do it with `COPY` command or with another way ?

My command is style (`select column1, column2 from table where condition = xy`) and I'm using `cqlsh`.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

If you don't mind your data using a pipe ('|') as a delimiter, you can try using the `-e` flag on cqlsh.  The `-e` flag allows you to send a query to Cassandra from the command prompt, where you could redirect or even perform a grep/awk/whatever on your output.

```
$ bin/cqlsh -e'SELECT video_id,title FROM stackoverflow.videos' > output.txt
$ cat output.txt

 video_id                             | title
--------------------------------------+---------------------------
 2977b806-df76-4dd7-a57e-11d361e72ce1 |                 Star Wars
 ab696e1f-78c0-45e6-893f-430e88db7f46 | The Witches of Whitewater
 15e6bc0d-6195-4d8b-ad25-771966c780c8 |              Pulp Fiction

(3 rows)
```

Older versions of cqlsh don't have the `-e` flag.  For older versions of cqlsh, you can put your command into a file, and use the `-f` flag.

```
$ echo "SELECT video_id,title FROM stackoverflow.videos;" > select.cql
$ bin/cqlsh -f select.cql > output.txt
```

From here, doing a `cat` on output.txt should yield the same rows as above.

Comment: Yeh it should resolve my problem, and that what i want to do. exept that it doesn't recognize the -e option.                       Usage: cqlsh [options] [host [port]] ----- i missed anything ?

cqlsh: error: no such option: -e

Comment: @user3196353 You must be running on an older version.  Edit made...try -f with a command file instead.

Comment: another quick question - how do i do that when i have where and string parametes: cqlsh -e'SELECT * from dev.photos where uid='score_test4'' > output.txt - does not work

Comment: @arseny In that case, you can also use `cqlsh -e` with double-quotes: `cqlsh -e"SELECT * from dev.photos where uid='score_test4';" > output.txt`

Comment: This gives 100 results into the CSV, if we have more results than that which are retrieved by clicking 'MORE' in the interactive mode, how do we go about getting them the CSV?

Comment: @JagratiGogia prepend your query with `PAGING OFF;`. E.g. `cqlsh -e "PAGING OFF; SELECT * FROM stackoverflow.videos;"`

Comment: ```cqlsh -e 'select word from inventory.blacklisted_token'
Usage: cqlsh.py [options] [host [port]]

cqlsh.py: error: 'from' is not a valid port number.``` does not seem to work for me

Comment: Can we do formatting of output.txt file? When i open the file,all the values of title column are right aligned and spaces are being appended at the beginning of the value. can we align them left?

Answer (score 51):

1. Use **CAPTURE** command to export the query result to a file.

> ```
> cqlsh> CAPTURE
> cqlsh> CAPTURE '/home/Desktop/user.csv';
> cqlsh> select *from user;
> Now capturing query output to '/home/Desktop/user.csv'.
> ```

Now, view the output of the query in **/home/Desktop/user.csv**

2. Use DevCenter and execute a query. Right click on the output and select "Copy All as CSV" to paste the output in CSV.

[image]

Comment: Option 2 is simple, except that DevCenter limits the output rows to 1000, unless you are using 1.6: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37862375/why-does-devcenter-of-datastax-has-row-restrictions-to-1000

Comment: This (option 1) seems to be a much better option than the accepted answer.

Comment: Actually, I think I misunderstand - option 1 doesn't output in CSV format, it just redirects the existing output to a file whose name ends in `.csv`, right?

Comment: yes. you can use "COPY TO" to export data from a table into a CSV file.

Answer (score 14):

In 2020th you can use [DSBulk](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/index.html) to export or import data to/from CSV (by default), or JSON. It could be as simple as:

```sh
dsbulk unload -k keyspace -t table -u user -p password -url filename
```

DSBulk is heavily optimized for fast data export, without putting too much load onto the coordinator node that happens when you just run `select * from table`.

You can control what columns to export, and even provide your own query, etc. See following blog posts for examples:

- https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/03/datastax-bulk-loader-introduction-and-loading
- https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/04/datastax-bulk-loader-more-loading
- https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/04/datastax-bulk-loader-common-settings
- https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/06/datastax-bulk-loader-unloading
- https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/07/datastax-bulk-loader-counting
- https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/12/datastax-bulk-loader-examples-loading-other-locations

Answer (score 11):

I just wrote a tool to export CQL query to CSV and JSON format. Give it a try :)

https://github.com/tenmax/cqlkit

Comment: I would have given it a try...if a had java8 :(

Comment: It looks like this is the only answer that lets you stream output in CSV format.  +1.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the COPY command to create the CSV file. e.g. copy table with selected columns. Columns are optional, if you select them, every column will be picked.

`COPY TABLE (COL1, COL2) TO 'filename.csv' HEADER=TRUE/FALSE`

For more reference
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshCopy.html

Comment: But how do you add `where`-conditions?

Answer (score 7):

Cannot comment... To deal with "MORE" issue when there are more than 100 rows, simply add "paging off" before the SQL.

Something like

```
$ bin/cqlsh -e'PAGING OFF;SELECT video_id,title FROM stackoverflow.videos' > output.txt
```

This will cause a little messy at the beginning of the output file but can easily be removed afterwards.

Answer (score 7):

With bash:

If you need to query the data (not possible with COPY TO) and if you need the final product to be importable (ie with COPY FROM):

```
cqlsh -e "SELECT * FROM bar WHERE column = 'baz' > raw_output.txt
```

Then you can reformat the output with `sed`

```
sed 's/\ //g; /^----.*/d; /^(/d; /^\s*$/d;' raw_output.txt | tee clean_output.csv
```

Which pretty much says

```
sed 'remove spaces; remove the column boarder; remove lines beginning with (COUNT X); and remove blank lines' | write output into clean_output.csv
```

The sed regexp's could be cleaned up to better suite your specific case, but thats the general idea.

Comment: That’s most probably will timeout when you have a lot of data

Comment: @AlexOtt I was surprised, but that's exactly what happened when I tried this. Good catch.

Comment: @dixon1e that's why it's important to use something like DSBulk for big amounts of data...

Comment: Nice, was unaware of DSBulk. Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I believe DevCenter also allows you to copy to CSV.
http://www.datastax.com/what-we-offer/products-services/devcenter

Answer (score 4):

In windows, double quotes should be used to enclose the CQL.

`cqlsh -e"SELECT video_id,title FROM stackoverflow.videos" > output.txt`

Answer (score 3):

If I am understanding correctly you want to redirect your output to stdout?

Put your cql command in a file. My files is called select.cql and contents are:

```
select id from wiki.solr limit 100;
```

Then issue the following and you get it to stdout:

```
cqlsh < select.cql
```

I hope this helps. From there on you can pipe it and add commas, remove headers etc.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but it's not what i really need, i'm searching for redirecting the output of my sql query to a csv file (stdout > file.csv) so i can use it in other jobs

Comment: Yep, that's what that does. The result of the query stored in the cql file is outputted to stdout. Sometimes, for complex or long queries, you store them in a file rather than write them in the cmd line. Then you can 'send' the file with the query to cql and you get the output to stdout. For one-liners and simple queries there is the other method as well.

Comment: in hindsight, you're right, i must have misunderstood you the first time, the other answer seemed a little more clear to me, sorry

Answer (score 2):

As the other guys have suggested, export the standard query output using ./cqlsh -e 'SELECT ...' > data.csv.

Once you have this you can easiliy replace the pipes ( | ) with commas using Excel (if you have it installed).

1. First open your file in a text editor (vi/notepad++) and delete the separator that Cass puts in (-----+-------+---), as well as the info on the number of rows from the bottom.
2. Open a new Excel workbook.
3. Click on the Data tab.
4. Click on "From Text/CSV" (top left).
5. Select your file, specifiy the pipe symbol as a delimiter, click Load.
6. That will create an .xlsx file so you'll have to Save As .csv manually. That will strip Excel's  formatting and leave you with commas.

Comment: please don't do that... it's simply not scalable

Answer (score 1):

Here, when using Cassandra on a docker container with SSL and authentication:

```
docker exec -it <cassandra_container> cqlsh -u <user> -p <password> --ssl -e  "select column1, column2 from table where condition = xy" > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

CQL COPY is good option for importing or exporting data. But if you want to analyze some small query output you can run below command and save the output in a file.

**cqlsh -e "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = 'xyz' > queryoutput.txt**

However, you can use CAPTURE also for saving output of the query to analyze something

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps to selectively export & import the Cassandra data.

**Exporting:**

- Write all the select queries in a file named *dump.cql* like below

  paging off;

  select * from student where id=10;

  select * from student where id=15;

****Note:**** Paging off is mandatory above the queries to avoid limiting the query results to default 100 records

- Creating a dump

*cqlsh -u user_name -p 'password' ip_address -k keyspace_name -f dump.cql > dump.csv;*

(for remote machine)

or

*cqlsh -k keyspace_name -f dump.cql > dump.csv;*

(for local machine)

- Removing whitespace characters from dump(It avoids removing whitespace withing json data)

```html
sed -r 's/(\".*\")|\s*/\1/g' dump.csv > data_without_spaces.csv
```

**Importing:**

*cqlsh -e "copy keyspace_name.table_name from 'data_without_spaces.csv' with delimiter = '|';"*

Comment: it's bad idea to use `cqlsh` for that - there are specialized tools, like DSBulk ot do that

Comment: The question has asked about taking dump of a specific query, I don't think DSBulk will support that.

Comment: it perfectly supports that... via `-query` option, although for that query it's not required - it's just need to export 2 specific columns.  And given query is really scanning of the whole table that isn't very well supported in the `cqlsh` if you have a lot of data

Answer (score -1):

The person asking asked for CSV not text.

I did this hack get my results. It worked for me and I moved on with my day.

`me:~/MOOSE2# echo "USE ████it; select * from samples_daily_buffer where dog_id=██48;" | cqlsh --cqlversion="3.4.4" cassandra0.stage.███████ | sed -e "s/ 
| */,/g" | sed -e "s/^ *//g" | tail -n +4 > ./myfile.csv`