# Why does DevCenter of Datastax has row restrictions to 1000?

Tags: datastax

There is a limit of displaying 1000 rows for the tables in Datastax Devcenter. Any reason for having this option?

Because when queried as `SELECT count(*) FROM tablename;` 
the performance from Cassandra is going to be same whether displaying 1000 records or complete records set.

[image: Devcenter_rowLimit]

Answer (score 4):

DevCenter version 1.6.0 introduces result set paging which allows you to browse all the rows in your result set.

In DevCenter 1.6.0 the "with limit" value sets the paging size, e.g. the number of records to view per page and is still limited to 1000 maximum. However, now you can page forward (and back) through all of the query results.

A related new feature allows you to export all results to a file, either as CSV or INSERT statements. Right-click in the results view area and select "Export all results to File as [CSV|Insert]".

Comment: Paging is done using the two arrows at the bottom right corner under the results window https://imgur.com/a/keE7m

Answer (score 0):

This is by design; consider it as a safeguard that prevents you from potentially fetching thousands or millions of rows by accident, which, among other problems, could have a serious impact on your network's bandwidth usage.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the query in Datastax DevCenter 1.6 it displays the 1000 record in result as selected limit but if you export the same result to CSV it will give you all the record which you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

I run Datastax Devcenter 1.4.

I run the query with a limit and it provides me the actual count.
But LIMIT is limited to maximum value of signed integer (2147483647)

select count(*) from users LIMIT 2147483647;-- ALLOW FILTERING;