# excess whitespace in cqlsh SHOW SESSION

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cqlsh, nosql

When attempting to show a session in CQLSH i'm getting an excessive amount of white space between each returned line, is there a way of removing the whitespace as what i'm getting is unreadable.

An example is below, i've trimmed hundreds of lines of whitespace, leaving enough in to demonstrate the point.

```
cqlsh:system_traces> SHOW SESSSION sessionid

Read 1 live and 0 tombstone cells [SharedPool-Worker-3] | 2017-07-05 
09:27:24.194001 | 127.0.0.1 |         151744





























Request complete | 2017-07-05 09:27:24.188936 | 127.0.0.1 |         151936
```

Comment: I am using cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.10. I do not see such a behaviour. Which version are you using ?

Comment: I've found the reason, i have an incredible number of token ranges that is creating an enormous column in one of the rows, so a large amount of white space is being added to the other rows for formatting. I only found this because I used `-e` to output to a file, which i had to open with vim as it was large enough to lag out other editors, i'll add an answer with a link to the stack question that lead me to the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to the problem is to output to a file as directed by: [StackOverflow - Export cassandra query result to a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26911405/2573045) and read it with a text editor such as vim that can handle a crazy amount of whitespace without lagging.

What happened was there were an exceedingly large number of token ranges which stretched the width of a column so that each proceeding row needed a very large amount of whitespace to keep formatting.