# How to COPY data from cassandra table to CSV with where claues?

Tags: cassandra-2.0

I need to get selective data copied to CSV file from Cassandra table as the query results is about million records. how to i do it with COPY command

select * from table1 where date='20190825'

cussrently using belo query which is giving all table data
COPY FROM table1  to /tmp/25Aug.csv

i need to get data copied to csv file for only seleted date.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use CQL COPY to extract specific rows to a CSV file.
See COPY syntax https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshCopy.html

Your options are:

- DataStax bulk loader = dsbulk. See example at https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-unloading and homepage https://github.com/datastax/dsbulk
- Call cqlsh with query statement and redirect output to a file at the shell level
- use cql CAPTURE command to send query output to a file

These answers are just a summary from [Export cassandra query result to a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26909408/export-cassandra-query-result-to-a-csv-file)